# how to remove delimiters in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have tried already the code below and it does not remove the delimeters in a dat file:

```
StreamReader input = new StreamReader(txtFile.Text);
string content = input.ReadToEnd().Trim();
string[] split = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(content, "\\s+", RegexOptions.None);
foreach (string s in split)
{
    txtStatus.Text = s + "\r\n" +  txtStatus.Text;
}
```

here is a sample data from the dat file I am working on:

> xú  !'                     Date       D                  Time       C                    Millitm    N                  TagIndex   N                  Value      C                  Status     C!                  Marker     C"                  Internal   C#
>    2020032403:25:25829    0       @ Bÿÿÿÿ 2020032403:25:25829    1      9@ Bÿÿÿÿ 2020032403:25:26844    0       @       2020032403:25:26844    1      9@      2020032403:25:27845    0       @      2020032403:25:27845    1      :@      2020032403:25:28847    0       @      2020032403:25:28847    1      ;@      2020032403:25:29851    0       @      2020032403:25:29851    1      <@      2020032403:25:30857    0       @      2020032403:25:30857    1      =@          2020032403:25:31861    0       @
>       2020032403:25:31861    1      >@      2020032403:25:32867    0       @      2020032403:25:32867    1      ?@
>       2020032403:25:33873    0       @      2020032403:25:33873    1      @@      2020032403:25:34877    0       @      2020032403:25:34877    1     €@@      2020032403:25:35879    0       @      2020032403:25:35879    1      A@      2020032403:25:36888    0       @      2020032403:25:36888    1     €A@      2020032403:25:37890    0       @      2020032403:25:37890    1      B@      2020032403:25:38838    0       @      2020032403:25:38838    1     €B@      2020032403:25:39841    0       @      2020032403:25:39841    1      C@      2020032403:25:40846    0       @      2020032403:25:40846    1     €C@      2020032403:25:41849    0       @      2020032403:25:41849    1      D@      2020032403:25:42851    0       @       2020032403:25:42851    1     €D@  !    2020032403:25:43852    0       @  "    2020032403:25:43852    1      E@  #    2020032403:25:44860    0       @  $    2020032403:25:44860    1     €E@  %    2020032403:25:45862    0       @  &    2020032403:25:45862    1      F@  '    2020032403:25:46869    0       @  (    2020032403:25:46869    1     €F@  )    2020032403:25:47873    0       @  *    2020032403:25:47873    1      G@  +    2020032403:25:48883    0       @  ,    2020032403:25:48883    1     €G@  -    2020032403:25:49887    0       @  .    2020032403:25:49887    1      H@  /    2020032403:25:50842    0       @  0    2020032403:25:50842    1     €H@  1    2020032403:25:51844    0       @  2    2020032403:25:51844    1      I@  3    2020032403:25:52866    0       @  4    2020032403:25:52866    1     €I@  5    2020032403:25:53868    0       @  6    2020032403:25:53868    1      J@  7    2020032403:25:54884    0       @  8    2020032403:25:54884    1     €J@  9    2020032403:25:55886    0       @  :    2020032403:25:55886    1      K@  ;    2020032403:25:56896    0       @  <    2020032403:25:56896    1     €K@  =    2020032403:25:57860    0       @  >    2020032403:25:57860    1      L@  ?    2020032403:25:58866    0       @  @    2020032403:25:58866    1     €L@  A    2020032403:25:59868    0       @  B    2020032403:25:59868    1      M@  C    2020032403:26:00873

can anyone help me?

Comment: What are the delimiters supposed to be?

Comment: all the special character, just would like to know if there is any possible solution that I can remove them all?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of special characters. To remove all characters except numbers, alphabets, spaces and ":" you can use following pattern `[^0-9a-zA-Z:\s]+`

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
txtStatus.Text = s + "\r\n" +  txtStatus.Text;
```